# How do I concatenate several different variables to create a URL

Tags: javascript, html-table, concatenation

I'm trying to use a for loop to generate a bunch of different urls to use in my table via Javascript.

The final url that i want is: http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-nb4-caxl-14u-12-aag.html

The url is basically broken down into 4 sections:

1. prefix: 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/'
2. product name: 'environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-'
3. product number: 'nb4-caxl-14u-12-aag'
4. suffix: '.html'

The prefix and suffix wont be changing. The product name will also stay the same within the javascript but I want it as a separate variable because I plan on making a bunch of javascripts, 1 for each different product name. The product number WILL change for each different row and link in my table.

This is what I have so far:

```
var eo_url_1 = 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/';
var eo_url_ext = "environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-"
var eo_url_2 = '.html';
```

I also have a for loop that is generating my part number and when i use console log I get this:

```
console.log(eopartnum[i]); //yields the following part number results
//NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAG
//NB4-CAXL-14U-12-BAG
//NB4-CAXL-14U-12-CAG
//(24 more similar results)
```

So for example eopartnum[0] = NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAG. I tried to use this to concatenate everything:

```
window.navtoprod = function() {
  window.document.location = eo_url_1.concat(eo_url_ext,eopartnum[i],eo_url_2);
}
```

but it seems to be giving me an error with the part number either by trying to direct me to 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-undefined' or 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-[object%20text]'

Here is the w3 that I've been working in: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0VL5U0MKS2H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the other answers here are valid if you are wanting to interpolate variable values into a string. Looking at the w3 example you provided, i instead think your issue is more to do with variable scope, in that as you have a generic method and you are looping over your products, you lose the concept of what the variable `eopartnums` is.

For your specific example, it may be better instead to read the product code direct from the table row, see the changed method below

```
window.navtoprod = function(evt) {
  var eo_url_1 = 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/';
  var eo_url_2 = '.html';
  var partNum = evt.target.parentNode.children[0].innerText;
  window.document.location = eo_url_1.concat(eo_url_ext,partNum,eo_url_2);
}
```

Comment: Interesting I tried using that i was returned this error: Refused to display 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAE.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. - This makes me think the code worked because the url looks correct, and the error lies somewhere else. Is it possible that w3 is cause me the issue? Im not really sure what it means by X-Frame-Options

Comment: That will be related to the W3 code tool yes, as your code is housed in an IFrame, and you are trying to re-direct your IFrameto the enviroptics.com website. This server is configured to send a header of `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN`. The `SAMEORIGIN` setting is a directive to say  that page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

Once you run the code in your normal browser / application (I.e. not in the W3 website) it will work fine.

Comment: What if the place I'm running it in my actual website is also in an iframe? Will it still work sinec I didnt set sameorigin as a setting?

Comment: If you are putting the iframe on a page under the enviroptics.com domain, the iframe will work fine. If not you will run into similar security issues because of W3C Cross Origin Resource Sharing

Comment: I tried it out and it seems to work great except that I can't get the first cell to follow the same rule. The first cell is an actual link and i wanted to link it with the same url as the one generated in the navtoprod function - However in the code the link and href are set before the function and when i try to move the function higher up in the code in changes the url. Is there an easy way around this? In my w3 that i posted earlier the first cell was just linking to enviroptics home page but Ideally id like to link it to the same url that we just created

Comment: You could remove the link and just have it output the product code, then the click handler to redirect to the product url should work as normal?

Comment: Yeah that works ill just have to change the css to make it look like a link since it wont get the default link formatting anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to use window.open with your code? When i tried it changes the part number to something else. I'm not really sure how your code is working with the evt.target.parentNode.children[0]

Answer (score 1):

Change the window.navtoprod as below

```
window.navtoprod = function() {
  window.document.location = eo_url_1.concat(eo_url_ext,this.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,eo_url_2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var eo_url_1 = 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/';
var eo_url_ext = "environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-"
var eo_url_2 = '.html',
    yourCode= 'aaaa-aaaa-aaaa',
    resultUrl=eo_url_1+eo_url_ext+yourCode+eo_url_2;

console.log(resultUrl);
```

or

```
var eo_url_1 = 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/';
    var eo_url_ext = "environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-";
    var eo_url_2 = '.html',
        yourCode= 'aaaa-aaaa-aaaa',
        resultUrl=''+eo_url_1.concat(eo_url_ext,yourCode,eo_url_2);

    console.log(resultUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 has introduced a nice way for you to be able to interpolate variable values into a string.  I have created a JSFiddle with an example using your scenario [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LLgLzv85/1/).

Here is a snippet using that example that logs to the console the URLs

```
var eo_url_1 = 'http://www.enviroptics.com/ecommerce/';
var eo_url_ext = "environmentally-sealed-thermocouple-"
var eo_url_2 = '.html';
var eopartnum = [
  'NB4-CAXL-14U-12-AAG',
  'NB4-CAXL-14U-12-BAG', 
  'NB4-CAXL-14U-12-CAG'
];

for(var index = 0; index < eopartnum.length; index++){
  var url = `${eo_url_1}${eo_url_ext}${eopartnum[index]}${eo_url_2}`;
  console.log(url);
}
```

Which will result in the following logging to the console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If my overview of your code is right `i` won't be available in the function `window.navtoprod`. I see places where `window.navtoprod` is registered as event handler, but I don't see any place where `i` is declared as global variable. So, the function can't choose a product number because it does not know which one. You can change `window.navtoprod` so that it finds out `i` on it's own. I guess it depends on the table row. This can be found out by using the event - object that is passed to the function as event handler.

Comment: Well the function was defined inside my for-loop, so doesnt that mean that the value i will be whatever it is during the for loop when the function is called?

Comment: The value of i is the value it had during definition of the function in this case (cp. closure). But if the function is assigned to window.navtoprod there is only one such function with only one value of i.